# Phonegap build with admob plugin

Tags: admob, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have tried to integrate Phone-gap as well Ad-mob plugin. reference git https://github.com/floatinghotpot/phonegap-admob-demo
It shows dummy ads even when I tried with my valid publisher id. How to change this??? Someone could help me please.

Comment: I think it is the debug version, not released build

Comment: Where you create the banner you probably pass in an option that says `isTesting: true` if so change it to `isTesting: false`

Comment: thanks will harris